# Create a video from a track (GPX / KML) using Google Street View images

Tags: python, google-maps, gps, pyqt5, google-street-view

I am trying to create a video from a track in GPX or KML format from Google Street view images.

If I enter the data of the coordinates of a location, I can generate a JPG with that image.

My problem is that when I want it to be several points, then I can't do it.

I have tried to see if through the loaded page control I can do it, but it only does it with the last point that I send you.

Any idea how to do it?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication,QMainWindow,QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout,QSplitter,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl,QRect,QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView,QWebEngineProfile,QWebEngineSettings
import sys
import time


class Video_Google_Street(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.showMaximized()
        
        # Create GUI
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.layoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.web_view=QWebEngineView(self.layoutWidget)
        self.file_Gpx = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.file_Gpx.setText('GPX')
        self.pb_fixed_point = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pb_fixed_point.setText('Fixed Point')
        self.pb_list_points = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pb_list_points.setText('List of Points')
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.web_view)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.file_Gpx )
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pb_fixed_point)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pb_list_points)
        
        # Create Slots
        # Slot when page is loaded
        self.web_view.loadProgress.connect(self.webLoading)
        self.file_Gpx.clicked.connect(self.select_track)
        self.pb_fixed_point.clicked.connect(self.fixed_point)
        self.pb_list_points.clicked.connect(self.list_points)
        
        self.loaded=0 # For control how many times Google Street give page loaded. Give 4 or 6 times
                
    def webLoading(self,event):
        if event==100: # For control how many times Google Street give page loaded. Give 4 or 6 times
            self.loaded+=1
            print(self.loaded)
            if self.loaded==6: # When give 6 loaded pages, then I grab the image
                height=self.web_view.page().contentsSize().height()
                width=self.web_view.page().contentsSize().width()
                self.web_view.grab(QRect(0,0,width,height)).save(self.file_name_jpg, b'JPG')
                self.loaded=0 # Restart Counter
    
    def fixed_point(self):
        # For test one fixed point
        page='https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint=42.2410144284368,0.965725583955646&heading=186.20048419497363&pitch=0'
        url = QUrl(page)        
        self.file_name_jpg='c:/temp/jpg/Fixed_Point.jpg'
        self.web_view.page().load(url)
        
    def list_points(self):
        # For test a list of points
        points=[[42.2410144284368, 0.965725583955646], [42.2409574314952, 0.965720470994711], [42.240896243602, 0.965715777128935], [42.2408291045576, 0.965709993615747], [42.2407593671232, 0.965707311406732], [42.240682002157, 0.965706137940288], [42.2406058106571, 0.965705132111907], [42.2405290324241, 0.965702198445797], [42.2404542658478, 0.96570186316967], [42.2403736319393, 0.965694990009069], [42.2402878012508, 0.965689290314913], [42.2402046527714, 0.965683842077851], [42.2401182353497, 0.965680154040456], [42.2400250285864, 0.965676885098219], [42.2399284690619, 0.965670766308904], [42.239836268127, 0.965669928118587], [42.2397397086024, 0.965669760480523], [42.2396446578205, 0.965668670833111], [42.2395426500589, 0.965667329728603], [42.2394416481256, 0.965666742995381], [42.2393352817744, 0.965665988624096], [42.239225897938, 0.965662971138954], [42.2391161788255, 0.965662384405732], [42.2390032745898, 0.965660456568003], [42.238890286535, 0.965660959482193], [42.2387754544616, 0.965657522901893], [42.2386588621885, 0.965651236474514], [42.2385448683053, 0.965645201504231], [42.2384282760322, 0.965633047744632], [42.2383137792349, 0.965623240917921], [42.2381979413331, 0.965607399120927], [42.2380880545825, 0.965586444362998], [42.2379776649177, 0.965560711920261], [42.2378623299301, 0.965525507926941], [42.2377466596663, 0.965477395802736], [42.2376317437738, 0.965427858754992], [42.2375180851668, 0.965373795479536], [42.2374019119889, 0.965305985882878], [42.2372817993164, 0.965243289247155], [42.2371708229184, 0.965186543762684], [42.2370388079435, 0.965118734166026], [42.2369178570807, 0.965059977024794], [42.2367867641151, 0.965002393350005], [42.2366627119482, 0.964955454692245], [42.2365273442119, 0.964910443872213], [42.2363934852183, 0.96487800590694], [42.2362439520657, 0.964843891561031], [42.2360911499709, 0.964822098612785], [42.235938096419, 0.964814722537994], [42.2357739787549, 0.96481841057539], [42.2356092743576, 0.964833246544003], [42.2354392055422, 0.964861242100596], [42.235277434811, 0.96489611081779], [42.2350895125419, 0.964943552389741], [42.2349150013179, 0.964991580694914], [42.2347342036664, 0.965042291209102], [42.2345569264144, 0.965098952874541], [42.2343808226287, 0.965155195444822], [42.2342006955296, 0.965212108567357]]
        self.file_name='List_Of_Points____' # Name used to save capture in JPG file
        self.load_street_view(points)
        
    def select_track(self):
        # For test with a GPX or KML file
        #self.file_name_gpx='c:/temp/jpg/GRMN6969.gpx'
        self.file_name_gpx,_ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Selecciona Fichero Track','c:/' , 'TRACK (*.gpx *.kml)')
        self.read_track(self.file_name_gpx)

    def read_track(self, file_name):
        # Read a KML or GPX and convert in a list of points
        from xml.dom import minidom

        if file_name:
            points=[]
            doc = minidom.parse(file_name)
            if file_name[-3:].upper()=='KML':
                coordinates = doc.getElementsByTagName('coordinates')[0].firstChild.data
                for element in coordinates.split():
                    lat=float(element.split(',')[0])
                    lon=float(element.split(',')[1])
                    points.append([lat,lon])
                    
            elif file_name[-3:].upper()=='GPX':
                track = doc.getElementsByTagName("trkpt")
                for punto in track:
                    lat=float(punto.getAttribute("lat"))
                    lon=float(punto.getAttribute("lon"))
                    points.append([lat,lon])
                    
            self.load_street_view(points)        
        
    def load_street_view(self, points):
        # Read a list of points and
        # Load a web page of Street view
        
        for position in range(len(points)):
            lat=points[position][0]
            lon=points[position][1]
            if not position==len(points)-1: # If it's the last point i can't calculate bearing
                bearing=self.cal_bearing(lat,lon,points[position+1][0],points[position+1][1])
                
            self.file_name_jpg=self.file_name[:-4]+"_"+str(position).zfill(5)+'.jpg'

            # For testing use. See terms of use of Google
            #page=('https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint={},{}&heading={}&pitch=0').format(str(lat),str(lon),bearing)
            
            # Using Google API
            page=('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location={},{}&heading={}&pitch=0&key=YOUR_API_KEY').format(str(lat),str(lon),bearing)    
            url = QUrl(page)   
            self.loaded=0 
            self.web_view.page().load(url)  
        
    def cal_bearing(self,lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
        """ Calculate bearing between two coordinates """
        from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians, degrees 
        lat1 = radians(lat1) 
        lon1 = radians(lon1) 
        lat2 = radians(lat2) 
        lon2 = radians(lon2) 
        dLon = lon2 - lon1
        y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2)
        x = cos(lat1)* sin(lat2) - sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(dLon)
        initial_bearing = atan2(x, y)
        # Now we have the initial bearing but math.atan2 return values
        # from -180° to + 180° which is not what we want for a compass bearing
        # The solution is to normalize the initial bearing as shown below
        initial_bearing = degrees(initial_bearing)
        compass_bearing = (initial_bearing + 360) % 360
        compass_bearing -=80 # I don't know why, but I have to correct with -80
        return compass_bearing
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Video_Google_Street()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this "home made" solution:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication,QMainWindow,QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl,QRect

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys,os

# Por Hacer
# Rehacer ficheros no creados bien
# Crear GPX con el tiempo correcto para el DashCamm
# Poder establecer los Frames por segundo

class Video_Google_Street(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,file_name=None,dir_destiny=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.showMaximized()
        
        # Create GUI
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.layoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.web_view=QWebEngineView(self.layoutWidget)
        self.file_Gpx = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.file_Gpx.setText('GPX')
        self.pb_fixed_point = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pb_fixed_point.setText('Fixed Point')
        self.pb_list_points = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pb_list_points.setText('List of Points')
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pb_list_points)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.file_Gpx )
        #self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pb_fixed_point)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.web_view)
        
        # Create Slots
        # Slot when page is loaded
        self.web_view.loadProgress.connect(self.webLoading)
        self.file_Gpx.clicked.connect(self.select_track)
        self.pb_fixed_point.clicked.connect(self.fixed_point)
        self.pb_list_points.clicked.connect(self.list_points)
        
        self.loaded=0 # For control how many times Google Street give page loaded. Give 4 or 6 times
        self.position=-1 # For control position of point processed
        
        # If not exit directory destiny ask for.
        if not dir_destiny:
            self.dir_destiny=QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory Destiny of Pictures")
        else:
            self.dir_destiny=dir_destiny
        
        # If file GPX exist, then start to create JPG
        if file_name:
            self.file_name_gpx=file_name
            self.read_track(self.file_name_gpx)
                
    def webLoading(self,event):
        # Called when page is loading - Event percentaje of loading
        
        if event==100: # For control how many times Google Street give page loaded. Give 4 or 6 times
            # Increase number of times is loaded
            self.loaded+=1
            print(self.loaded)
            # For me give 5 loaded pages when really image is created, then I grab the image
            if self.loaded==5: 
                # Get size of screen/widget to create JPG
                height=self.web_view.page().contentsSize().height()
                width=self.web_view.page().contentsSize().width()

                # Create secuential name of JPG
                self.file_name_jpg=self.dir_destiny+'/'+ os.path.basename(self.file_name_gpx).split('.')[0]+"_"+str(self.position).zfill(5)+'.jpg'
                
                # Capture Image
                self.web_view.grab(QRect(0,0,width,height)).save(self.file_name_jpg, b'JPG')
                
                self.loaded=0 # Restart Counter
                print(self.file_name_jpg)
                
                # If there is a list then continue calling more points
                if self.position>-1:
                    # If it is not the final point
                    if self.position<len(self.points):
                        # Save JPG with GPS Coordinates
                        self.save_exif(self.file_name_jpg,self.points[self.position][0],self.points[self.position][1])
                        # Call to load another Point
                        self.load_street_view() 
                        # Increase for next point
                        self.position+=1
                    else:
                        # Join JPG to create a Video
                        self.create_video()
    
    def fixed_point(self):
        # For test one fixed point
        page='https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint=42.2410144284368,0.965725583955646&heading=186.20048419497363&pitch=0'
        url = QUrl(page)        
        self.file_name_jpg='c:/temp/jpg/Fixed_Point.jpg'
        self.web_view.page().load(url)
        
    def list_points(self):
        # For test a list of points
        points=[[42.2410144284368, 0.965725583955646], [42.2409574314952, 0.965720470994711], [42.240896243602, 0.965715777128935], [42.2408291045576, 0.965709993615747], [42.2407593671232, 0.965707311406732], [42.240682002157, 0.965706137940288], [42.2406058106571, 0.965705132111907], [42.2405290324241, 0.965702198445797], [42.2404542658478, 0.96570186316967], [42.2403736319393, 0.965694990009069], [42.2402878012508, 0.965689290314913], [42.2402046527714, 0.965683842077851], [42.2401182353497, 0.965680154040456], [42.2400250285864, 0.965676885098219], [42.2399284690619, 0.965670766308904], [42.239836268127, 0.965669928118587], [42.2397397086024, 0.965669760480523], [42.2396446578205, 0.965668670833111], [42.2395426500589, 0.965667329728603], [42.2394416481256, 0.965666742995381], [42.2393352817744, 0.965665988624096], [42.239225897938, 0.965662971138954], [42.2391161788255, 0.965662384405732], [42.2390032745898, 0.965660456568003], [42.238890286535, 0.965660959482193], [42.2387754544616, 0.965657522901893], [42.2386588621885, 0.965651236474514], [42.2385448683053, 0.965645201504231], [42.2384282760322, 0.965633047744632], [42.2383137792349, 0.965623240917921], [42.2381979413331, 0.965607399120927], [42.2380880545825, 0.965586444362998], [42.2379776649177, 0.965560711920261], [42.2378623299301, 0.965525507926941], [42.2377466596663, 0.965477395802736], [42.2376317437738, 0.965427858754992], [42.2375180851668, 0.965373795479536], [42.2374019119889, 0.965305985882878], [42.2372817993164, 0.965243289247155], [42.2371708229184, 0.965186543762684], [42.2370388079435, 0.965118734166026], [42.2369178570807, 0.965059977024794], [42.2367867641151, 0.965002393350005], [42.2366627119482, 0.964955454692245], [42.2365273442119, 0.964910443872213], [42.2363934852183, 0.96487800590694], [42.2362439520657, 0.964843891561031], [42.2360911499709, 0.964822098612785], [42.235938096419, 0.964814722537994], [42.2357739787549, 0.96481841057539], [42.2356092743576, 0.964833246544003], [42.2354392055422, 0.964861242100596], [42.235277434811, 0.96489611081779], [42.2350895125419, 0.964943552389741], [42.2349150013179, 0.964991580694914], [42.2347342036664, 0.965042291209102], [42.2345569264144, 0.965098952874541], [42.2343808226287, 0.965155195444822], [42.2342006955296, 0.965212108567357]]
        points=[[42.2410144284368, 0.965725583955646], [42.2409574314952, 0.965720470994711], [42.240896243602, 0.965715777128935], [42.2408291045576, 0.965709993615747], [42.2407593671232, 0.965707311406732], [42.240682002157, 0.965706137940288]]
        self.file_name_gpx='c:/temp/jpg/List_Of_Points' # Name used to save capture in JPG file
        self.load_street_view(points,first=True)
        
    def select_track(self):
        # For test with a GPX or KML file
        
        self.file_name_gpx,_ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Selecciona Fichero Track','c:/' , 'TRACK (*.gpx *.kml)')
        self.read_track(self.file_name_gpx)

    def read_track(self, file_name):
        # Read a KML or GPX and convert in a list of points
        from xml.dom import minidom
        

        if self.file_name_gpx:
            points=[]
            doc = minidom.parse(self.file_name_gpx)
            if self.file_name_gpx[-3:].upper()=='KML':
                coordinates = doc.getElementsByTagName('coordinates')[0].firstChild.data
                for element in coordinates.split():
                    lat=float(element.split(',')[0])
                    lon=float(element.split(',')[1])
                    points.append([lat,lon])
                    
            elif self.file_name_gpx[-3:].upper()=='GPX':
                track = doc.getElementsByTagName("trkpt")
                for punto in track:
                    lat=float(punto.getAttribute("lat"))
                    lon=float(punto.getAttribute("lon"))
                    points.append([lat,lon])
                    
            self.load_street_view(points,first=True)        

    def load_street_view(self, points=None,first=False):
        # Read a list of points and
        # Load a web page of Street view
        
        if first:
            self.points=points
            self.position=0

        lat=self.points[self.position][0]
        lon=self.points[self.position][1]
        if not self.position==len(self.points)-1: # If it's the last point i can't calculate bearing
            self.bearing=self.cal_bearing(lat,lon,self.points[self.position+1][0],self.points[self.position+1][1])

        # Using Google API
        page=('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location={},{}&heading={}&pitch=0&key=YOUR_API_KEY').format(str(lat),str(lon),self.bearing)

        # For testing use. See terms of use of Google
        page=('https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint={},{}&heading={}&pitch=0').format(str(lat),str(lon),self.bearing)
        
        url = QUrl(page)   
        self.loaded=0 
        self.web_view.page().load(url)  
        
    def cal_bearing(self,lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
        """ Calculate bearing between two coordinates """
        from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians, degrees 
        lat1 = radians(lat1) 
        lon1 = radians(lon1) 
        lat2 = radians(lat2) 
        lon2 = radians(lon2) 
        dLon = lon2 - lon1
        x = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2)
        y = cos(lat1)* sin(lat2) - sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(dLon)
        initial_bearing = atan2(x, y)
        # Now we have the initial bearing but math.atan2 return values
        # from -180° to + 180° which is not what we want for a compass bearing
        # The solution is to normalize the initial bearing as shown below
        initial_bearing = degrees(initial_bearing)
        compass_bearing = (initial_bearing + 360) % 360
        return compass_bearing

    def save_exif(self,fichero,lat,lon):
        # Save GPS data in JPG EXIF File
        from pyexiv2 import Image
        img = Image(fichero)
        exif_lat=str(int(lat))+"/1 "+str(int(lat % 1 * 60))+"/1 "+str(int(round((lat % 1 * 60)%1*60,4)*100))+"/100"
        exif_lon=str(int(lon))+"/1 "+str(int(lon % 1 * 60))+"/1 "+str(int(round((lon % 1 * 60)%1*60,4)*100))+"/100"
        if int(lat)<0:
            exif_lat_ref='S'
        else:
            exif_lat_ref='N'

        if int(lon)<0:
            exif_lon_ref='W'
        else:
            exif_lon_ref='E'

        description=''
        img.modify_exif({'Exif.Image.ImageDescription':description,'Exif.Image.Make':'Python Google Earth','Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitudeRef': exif_lat_ref,'Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude': exif_lat,'Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitudeRef': exif_lon_ref, 'Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitude': exif_lon})

    def create_video(self):
        # Call to FFMPEG to join JPG and create a Video
        cwd=os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.dir_destiny)
        output_video=self.dir_destiny+'/'+ os.path.basename(self.file_name_gpx).split('.')[0]+'.MP4'       
        order='''ffmpeg -framerate 1/0.5 -i {}_%5d.jpg -vf "crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" {}'''.format(os.path.basename(self.file_name_gpx).split('.')[0],output_video)
        os.system(order)
        os.chdir(cwd)
        self.exit()

    def exit(self):
        self.close()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Name of GPX File
    file_name_gpx='c:/temp/jpg/GRMN6969.gpx'
    file_name_gpx=None
    # Directory where create JPG
    dir_destiny='c:/temp/jpg/generated'
    win = Video_Google_Street(file_name_gpx,dir_destiny)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```